# Why is readonly input field not valid

Tags: html, css

Consider the following html:

```
<input bar value="bar">

<input foo readonly value="foo">
```

The weird thing here is that the first input element is valid and the second one is not just because it is readonly!

```
$('[bar]').is(':valid') === true

$('[foo]').is(':valid') === false
```

[DEMO/JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n1vykgxg/1/)

What is going on here ? And how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Readonly inputs are [barred from constraint validation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#barred-from-constraint-validation), according to [HTML5 docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute).

This means, a readonly input is neither valid nor invalid.

Here some code which demonstrates it ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/n1vykgxg/11/)):

HTML:

```
<input type="email" value="invalidemail">
<input type="email" value="valid@e.mail">

<input type="email" readonly value="invalidemail">
<input type="email" readonly value="valid@e.mail">
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
input:valid {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it makes more sense now :) I've updated the jsfiddle a bit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n1vykgxg/12/) to visualize it even more!